# in iphone sdk How To take a Pic using front camera When Screen is on

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I need to know who unlocked my phone. when unlock screen take a picture using front camera in background and save in gallery please help me.

or

how to give a functionality to phone when unlock screen

please

Comment: it might not be possible

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible if you iPhone is prison break. SDK will not allow APP to access.